# Dependent Drop-Down Lists with dynamic range as reference point

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using power query to generate a dynamic table (#2) from a table (#1) source. This query is automatically updating. This means if a new record is added to the table (#1) source, it will soon be added to the table (#2).

Because of how the dynamic table (#2) is structured, I am using this as a dependent drop-down source, and NOT the table (#1).

***Therefor I need a dependent drop-down setup that will have a dynamic reference for both drop-down #1 and drop-down #2 criteria.***

In addition, this whole setup should be expandable and exclude blank cells.

In order to achieve this I have been trying to modify [this](https://www.xelplus.com/excel-dynamic-dependent-drop-down-lists-exclude-blanks/) tutorial, by adding:

```
=A$4:(INDEX($4:$4;;COUNTA($4:$4)))
```

as a reference to the table headers. When adding this formula to the data validation I am getting an error:

«*You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria*»

I am thinking, if I can get this formula to somehow work for the drop-down #1 criteria, I can make a similar  reference for the drop-down #2 criteria. Something like this:

```
=OFFSET($A$4, 1, MATCH($F$4, <DYNAMIC-RANGE>,0)-1, COUNTA(OFFSET($A$4, 1, MATCH($F$4, <DYNAMIC-RANGE>,0)-1, 20, 1)),1,)
```

**At this point I need some advice that can lead me on the right track! Any help is much appreciated!**

[Modified version of the tutorial worksheet!](https://anonfiles.com/H8sfE5Ndu1/_MODIFIED_-Excel_Dependent_Dropdown_Expandable_Exclude_Empty_XelPlus_xlsx)

Comment: File in the link is not available

Comment: Just store your formula `=A$4:(INDEX($4:$4;;COUNTA($4:$4)))` as a Named Range first, then reference that in the Data Validation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your file, you can use [Spilled Range Operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd) in your Data Validation to add the output of `=A$4:(INDEX($4:$4;;COUNTA($4:$4)))` in dropdown.

If you added the above Index formula in Cell I5, then you data-validation for drop-down#1 will be `$I$5#`

Sample Screenshot:
[image: Spilled Range in Data Validation]